# Component not updating on changing state in React

Tags: reactjs

```
function App() {
    let [json, setJson] = useState([{ Name: "First", Age: "46" }]);

    function addRow() {
        setJson(json => json.concat({ Name: "Second", Age: 56 }));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="App">
                <Grid json={json} />

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {json.map((row, i) => <tr key={i}>{
                            Object.keys(row).map((col, i) => <td key={i}>{row[col]}</td>)
                        }</tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <button onClick={() => addRow()}>Add Row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the above code, when I click on the Button, the row gets added on the screen to the table element, but the Grid, which also renders a similar table, does not get updated. What am I missing?

PS: Code of Grid

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Grid(props) {
    let [data, setData] = useState(props.json);

    return <table>
        <tbody>
            {data.map((row, i) => <tr key={i}>{
                Object.keys(row).map((col, i) => <td key={i}>{row[col]}</td>)
            }</tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Depends on what the `Grid` is.

Comment: Please provide all relevant component code. What is `Grid` and what does it do?

Comment: Added the Grid code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your props are not updated because you are only using it for initial State.

You need to add useEffect so it updates the state on props change.

```
export default function Grid(props) {
    let def = { json: [{ Name: "Arun", Age: "46" }] }
    props = { ...def, ...props }

    let [data, setData] = useState(props.json); //this only set initial props

    useEffect(() => {

         setData(props.json) //u need to setData on props change
    },[props])
    return <table>
        <tbody>
            {data.map((row, i) => <tr key={i}>{
                Object.keys(row).map((col, i) => <td key={i}>{row[col]}</td>)
            }</tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Grid` is putting the initial `json` prop into state. When the prop changes, Grid's state doesn't update as well.

Since you aren't doing anything with the stateful value in Grid other than render it, I'd remove the state entirely - just render the props.

Your `json` prop isn't JSON either - to avoid confusion caused by the mislabled name, consider calling it something more accurate, maybe like `gridData`:

```
const initialGridData = [{ Name: "Arun", Age: "46" }]
export default function Grid({ gridData = initialGridData }) {
    return <table>
        <tbody>
            {gridData.map((row, i) => <tr key={i}>{
                Object.keys(row).map((col, i) => <td key={i}>{row[col]}</td>)
            }</tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are rendering stale state in `Grid`. When the passed `json` prop updates `Grid` doesn't update its cached copy in state.

## Solution

You *could* use an `useEffect` hook to update state, but this is an ***anti-pattern*** in React. Just render from the passed prop.

```
export default function Grid(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {props.json.map((row, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            {Object.keys(row).map((col, i) => (
              <td key={i}>{row[col]}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```